Create Concept2 ErgRace files from Excel or CSV
Concept2 ErgRace software allows to load .rac2 files (JSON) to run races.
It there any application capable of generating Concept2 ErgRace files starting from a spreadsheet (excel or CSV)?
Via google searches I couldn't find any

I found this free web app called "Spreadsheet to ErgRace files" that converts CSV or spreadsheet files into .rac2 files compatible with the Concept2 ErgRace software. They also provide some helpful example guides. This is the link https://spreadsheet2ergrace.81watts.com/
